# How can I clean high roof gutters?

Tags: roof, gutters

My house is a tall colonial. At the tallest point the gutters are almost 30 feet above ground. I do not have a tall ladder and do not want to climb on a roof which is even higher. I do have a gutter cleaning gadget with a steel fork at the end BUT it is only 5 feet long.

Is there a extension pole system or some other idea so I can raise this gadget up to 20 feet safely?

Comment: The possibility of any any significant debris caught in the top of the gutter system is slim. I would recommend a large tired man-lift with articulated boom arm.

Comment: Do you have trees that overhang the roof? If so, then you need to figure things out; if not, then you're probably OK.

Comment: @PaulLogan The chance of significant debris is only slim if there aren't any trees.  My house has 14 oaks on the lot, several of which are easily 70' tall.

Comment: Do you have neighbours with the same problem? Perhaps they get someone to come round and you could all get a cheaper rate by getting them all done around the same time.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use extension tubes on my wet/dry shopvac, along with a J attachment.  It works like a champ.  Just search for "gutter attachment for shop vac".  I have looked at the gutters after cleaning from above, and they are amazingly spotless.

Comment: That is a great suggestion @Evil Elf. Thanks

Comment: I finally got sick of cleaning my second story gutter.  I have a cape cod, so the majority is just one floor up, but my back dormer has about 30 feet of gutter.  I had a local gutter cleaner install gutter toppers for $5/per foot, here in Ohio.  So worth it.

Answer (score 1):

There comes a time when every do it yourselfer reaches the limit. In your case this may be yours. At some point the risk offsets the cost. Even with a forty foot ladder you will be working on the upper rungs. You will have a working range of a few feet on each side of the ladder. This means you will be moving the ladder 15 or 20 times. Unless you manhandle 40 foot ladders for a living it is a difficult and arduous task.  You may want to consider having the gutters evaluated. If you have large trees they may dropped leaves into you gutters. If they are clean now you may want to consider one of the many types of gutter- guard systems so they will stay clean.

Answer (score 0):

I would rent a Bil-JAX boom lift or small snorkel lift truck for the day.
These run about $250 per day in our area.

Then use a power washer to blow out the eave troughs.

Certainly much safer than a 40 foot extension ladder.

Good luck!